# Returning dictionary from function in vba. Error 450

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I wrote a function which create a dictionary and have faced with strange behavior: I can retrieve value by key only inside function. When i try to do it with dictionary returned by function, I receive `Run-time error '450'`
My code is:

```
Option Explicit
Function year_range_dict() As Object
    Dim d
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "a", "aaa"
    d.Add "b", "bbb"
    d.Add "c", "ccc"
    If d.Exists("c") Then
        MsgBox d("c")
        End If
    Set year_range_dict = d
End Function
Sub DefaultRates()
    MsgBox year_range_dict()("a"), "outside of function"
End Sub
```

When this code is run, I receive message box with "CCC" and then error message

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry for such idiotism: I forgot just one thing: Set. This is working code:

```
Option Explicit
Function year_range_dict() As Object
    Dim d
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "a", "aaa"
    d.Add "b", "bbb"
    d.Add "c", "ccc"
    If d.Exists("c") Then
        MsgBox d("c")
        End If
    Set year_range_dict = d
End Function
Sub DefaultRates()
    Dim d
    Set d=year_range_dict()
    MsgBox d("a")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Voila:

```
Function year_range_dict() As Object

    Dim d

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "a", "aaa"
    d.Add "b", "bbb"
    d.Add "c", "ccc"
    If d.Exists("c") Then
        MsgBox d("c")
    End If
    Set year_range_dict = d

End Function

Sub DefaultRates()

    MsgBox year_range_dict()("a")

End Sub
```

The problem was that you were giving additional parameter `"outside of function"`. No idea what you were trying to do with it, but `year_range_dict()("a")` returns the value of the dictionary for the key `"a"`.

---

If the idea of "outside of function" was that it should be the title of the `MsgBox`, then it should be like this: `MsgBox year_range_dict()("a"), Title:="outside of function"`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see the parameters of the MsgBox:

[image]